# Непонятны динамические трёхмерные массивы в c++ (их структура)

Tags: c++

Нужно сделать для задания трёхмерный массив, чтобы он был `arr[n][n][n]`, а `n` выбирается случайным образом в начале программы.

Будет ли этот код правильным для создания и удаления такого массива?

```
int*** cube = new int** [n];
for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
    cube[a] = new int* [n];
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
        cube[a][b] = new int[n];
    }
}

for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
        delete[] cube[a][b];
    }
    delete[] cube[a];
}
delete[] cube;
```

Comment: [трехзвездочный программистъ](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer), ну а вообще да, вроде правильный, только индексы стоит использовать с типом std::size_t.

Comment: Лучше не использовать указатели в обернуть все в https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html

Comment: еще вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309093/multi-dimensional-array-initialization-based-on-stdarray

Comment: В С++ нет многомерных массивов неконстантного размера. Организовать такой массив вы можете только сами, ручками. Как сделаете - так и будет. Для этого есть множество способов. С++ тут совершенно ни при чем. Ваш вариант - вполне правильный, но не единственный.